# how can I make a simple interactive web map (bigger than what google Chart API allows)

Tags: javascript, maps, google-visualization, countries

I have a spreadsheet with: URL, 2 digit country code, Main Value, Less important values ...

I just want to make a simple map that can be bigger than what Google Charts API allows (that one is limited to 600x600), but a similar level of simplicity.

If it looks nice and is interactive (hovering on country shows data) all the better. If I have to host my own javascript, that's OK.

Comment: I since went with Protovis (and d3)

 
[See this question for a breakdown of the two][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212104/protovis-vs-d3-js

Answer (score 1):

Maps can be any size you want:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMapOptions

It defaults to the size of the container it is in, so if you put it in a `div` that is 600x600, it will be that size.